# Flutter: is Dialog on top of Navigator (stack)?

Tags: asynchronous, flutter

How do I determine whether some dialog is being displayed or top of the stack is a dialog?

I have an `async` function that pushes a dialog (Like post request with loading dialog). When the response comes, loading the dialog closed(pop) then message dialog is pushed.

But the problem is:
If I send multiple requests, sometimes the loading screen stays on top...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool dialogIsVisible(BuildContext context) {
  bool isVisible = false;
  Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
    isVisible = route is PopupRoute;
    return !isVisible;
  });
  return isVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a `Dialog` is on top of the Navigator object by doing a little verification:

```
void _verifyDialog(context) {
    var _isDialogOnTop = false;
    var stackCount = 0;

    Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
      if (!_isDialogOnTop && route.toString().contains("_DialogRoute")) {
        _isDialogOnTop = true;
      }
      else{
        stackCount++;
      }

      return _isDialogOnTop || stackCount > 0;
    });

    print (_isDialogOnTop);
  }
```

Comment: `route.toString().contains("_DialogRoute")` seems too fragile and could be easily broken in a future Flutter release